# No option to connect to wireless network

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking

I don't have any option to connect to wireless on my brother's laptop. It just doesn't appear in the taskbar at all - even the no wireless networks were found doesn't appear. In network connections, I only have the option of using a wired connection. According to device manager, I have a working VIA Rhine II Fast Ethernet Adapter (this device only appeared after I selected showing hidden devices). I have already attempted restarting the computer a few times. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a laptop then look for a slider switch, with a little wireless symbol next to it, on the side of the unit and make sure it is not selected to off.

Answer (score 2):

A VIA Rhine II Fast Ethernet Adapter will not help you with wireless, Fast Ethernet generally refers to 100Mbps wired Ethernet.

Try searching for drivers for your laptop's wireless card on the manufacturer's website, or perform a Windows update with a wired connection (Windows Updates will usually detect and download appropriate drivers).